# Homomorphisms of the algebraic Torus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

> Any (holomorphic) group homomorphism $f:\mathbb{C}^\ast\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^\ast$ is of the form $f(z)=z^k$ ?

Is this true? I tried this: differentiating $f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$ with respect to $z$ gives:
$$\forall w\in\mathbb{C}^\ast \quad f_z(z)=w\cdot f_z(zw)\cdot f(1/w) $$
where $f_z=\partial_z f$. Choosing $w=1/z$, this leads to
$$ df=c\frac{f(z)}{z} dz ,$$
where $c=f_z(1)$. But then I am not sure how to use this to show $f(z)=z^c$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $f$ as a Laurent series $f(z)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}a_nz^n$.
   Now since $f(2z)=f(2)f(z)$, we have $$f(2z)=\sum a_n2^nz^n=f(2)\sum a_nz^n$$ so that for all $n\in \mathbb Z$ we deduce $2^na_n=f(2) a_n$.
This proves that  $a_n$ can be nonzero for only one $n$ : the $n_0=k$ with $f(2)=2^k$ .
Thus $f(z)$ is of the form $f(z)=a_kz^k$and the equation $f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$ translates into $a_kz^kw^k=a_kz^ka_kw^k$, forcing $a_k=a_k^2$ and thus $a_k=1$ (recall  $k$ was chosen so that $a_k\neq 0)$.

Hence  necessarily $f(z)=z^k$ for some integer $k\in \mathbb Z$, just as you wished.

Comment: That's very neat. Thank you.

Comment: It's a pleasure, Heitor.